# Chaining a post request after another post request in javascript using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api, method-chaining

I am trying to perform a post request, obtain the ids set as the primary key back, and use these to populate a different table through a different API.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311803/chaining-2-asynchronous-calls-promise-api-to-run-serially) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979376/multiple-api-calls-with-fetch-in-chain-and-promise-all) SO posts, as well as [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-nested-http-requests-using-the-fetch-api) article, but I keep getting the same error back.

Code for the API calls I have so far:

```js
  async function handleAdd () {
    const shiftTypes = await fetch('myURL/shift-type', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      // the following line is sending out an object representing a single ShiftType (from a react state)
      // e.g. { "abbreviation": "ld", "description": "long day", "start": "12:54:00", "end": "22:54:00"}
      body: JSON.stringify(newShiftType),
    })
      .then(response => response.json());
    // in the original code from this article the next line was this.shiftType = shiftType
    let shiftTypesTwo = shiftTypes;
    const shiftTypeIds = shiftTypesTwo.map(shiftType => shiftType.shift_type_id);

    //Now I would like to create 28 records in another table passing the shift_type_id as foreign key
    for (let i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
      const shifts = await fetch('myURL/shift', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          people_required: 42,
          shift_type_id: shiftTypeIds[0],
        }),
      });
      console.log(shifts);
    }
  }
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
ShiftTypes.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: shiftTypesTwo.map is not a function
    at handleAdd (ShiftTypes.js:38:1)
handleAdd   @   ShiftTypes.js:38
await in handleAdd (async)      
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1    @   react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @   react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

where line 38 refers to this

```js
const shiftTypeIds = shiftTypesTwo.map(shiftType => shiftType.shift_type_id);
```

piece of code from above.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional debugging I found the issue:

I believed that the return value of the first API was an array with one object inside of it. However, by inspecting that return value I discovered that in fact it was just an object, and not an array of objects.

As a result, it was impossible to use map on it.

By replacing line 38 with the following

```js
    const shiftTypeId = shiftTypes.shift_type_id;
```

I was able to access the shift_type_id directly and use this for the following API call.